# Js access to object with 2 elements inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, soapui

I trying to use SoapUi with node js, I have a node server with fonction which make calcul with 2 integer.

My object is :

```
{
  attributes: {
    'soapenv:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
  },
  weight: { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' }, '$value': '10' },
  distance: { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' }, '$value': '10' }
}
```

And I need to keep only

```
{ weight: '10', distance: '10' }
```

I have try to do some thing `args.weight.attributes['$value']` but nothing work.

Any Idea?

And this is not possible to change this return format of wsdl soap?

Answer (score 0):

you should use:

```
args.weight['$value']
args.distance['$value']
```

```js
let args = {
  attributes: {
    'soapenv:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
  },
  weight: { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' }, '$value': '10' },
  distance: { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' }, '$value': '10' }
}

console.log(args.weight['$value'])
console.log(args.distance['$value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be useful for you:

```
{ weight: obj.weight['$value'], distance: obj.distance['$value'] }
```

```js
let obj = {
  attributes: {
    'soapenv:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
  },
  weight: { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' }, '$value': '10' },
  distance: { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'xsd:int' }, '$value': '10' }
}

console.log(
  /*return*/{
    weight: obj.weight['$value'],
    distance: obj.distance['$value']
  }
 )
```